# Group similar meta_key values and create result set with meta_value data

Tags: mysql, grouping, meta-key

I have fields that look like this:

| meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| schedule_1_date | 2021/2/7 |
| schedule_1_lesson | 100 |
| schedule_2_date | 2020/12/30 |
| schedule_2_lesson | 105 |
| schedule_3_date | 2021/2/8 |
| schedule_3_lesson | 90 |
| schedule_4_date | 2021/5/10 |
| schedule_4_lesson | 91 |

I want to select the data to meet the condition:

- meta_value of schedule_%_date is 2021/2/7 or 2021/2/8
- the number of '%' in schedule_%_lesson is equal to the number of '%' in the first condition

For example, with the condition above, I will get these data:

| meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| schedule_1_date | 2021/2/7 |
| schedule_1_lesson | 100 |
| schedule_3_date | 2021/2/8 |
| schedule_3_lesson | 90 |

The code I've tried so far

`SELECT * FROM  'table_name'  WHERE (meta_key LIKE 'schedule_%_date' AND meta_value IN ('2021/02/07','2021/02/08')) OR (meta_key LIKE 'schedule_%_lesson')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one out:

```
SELECT tt.meta_key AS lesson_key, tt.meta_value AS lesson_value,
  d.meta_key AS date_key, d.meta_value AS date_value
FROM `table_name` tt
JOIN
  (SELECT t.*, REPLACE(REPLACE(t.meta_key, 'schedule_', ''), '_date', '') AS key_num
  FROM `table_name` t
  WHERE t.meta_key LIKE '%schedule%date%'
    AND t.meta_value IN ('2021/2/7', '2021/2/8')) d
      ON d.key_num = REPLACE(REPLACE(tt.meta_key, 'schedule_', ''), '_lesson', '')
WHERE tt.meta_key LIKE '%schedule%lesson%'
```

It outputs data in a slightly different format, thought it might work for you as well:

| lesson_key | lesson_value | date_key | date_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| schedule_1_lesson | 100 | schedule_1_date | 2021/2/7 |
| schedule_3_lesson | 90 | schedule_3_date | 2021/2/8 |

This query though might not be optimal from indexes utilization perspective. Make sure to take this into consideration. Using `%` wildcard in the `LIKE` statements in the middle of search string reduces the performance of index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REGEXP` operator to filter for rows where the `meta_key` follow the pattern `^schedule_[0-9]+_date$`. In a derived table also filter for the `meta_value` of such rows. Use `replace()` to remove the non-digit part from `meta_key` of that rows. Join that derived table to the actual table. In the `ON` clause you can build the wanted `meta_key`s using `concat()` and the digit part of the `meta_key`s from the derived table.

```
SELECT t1.meta_key,
       t1.meta_value
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT replace(replace(meta_key,
                                               'schedule_',
                                               ''),
                                       '_date',
                                       '') n
                               FROM elbat t2
                               WHERE t2.meta_key REGEXP '^schedule_[0-9]+_date$'
                                     AND t2.meta_value IN ('2021/2/7',
                                                           '2021/2/8')) n
                       ON t1.meta_key IN (concat('schedule_', n.n, '_date'),
                                          concat('schedule_', n.n, '_lesson'));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=72323d712e1c94a681615da59e8b17f0)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you don't have any use for the `meta_key` in your result set and that it is only used for grouping.

I find the table structure to be imperfectly designed for a pivot query, but with a few string trimming functions, a pivot can be used to simplify your result set (no subqueries are required).

Group on the characters before the second underscore in the `meta_key` column.  Then use aggregate functions to isolate the desired values in your SELECT.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

```
SELECT 
    MAX(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', -1) = 'date', meta_value, NULL)) `date`,
    MAX(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', -1) = 'lesson', meta_value, NULL)) `lesson`
FROM elbat
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2)
HAVING `date` IN ('2021/2/7', '2021/2/8');
```

| date | lesson |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/2/7 | 100 |
| 2021/2/8 | 90 |